# Altering Table but Foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql

I cannot link my items table to my categories table

here's the sql query i used:

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl_items` ADD FOREIGN KEY(`items_cat_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_items_cat`(`items_cat_id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

I already tried:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
<!-- SQL QUERY -->
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Here's the error:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/phDpRYI.png]

---

Here's my table structure:
[image]

Comment: The error is pretty clear.   The existing data in the column does not satisfy the foreign constraint.

Comment: got it! thanks, I forgot I have data on my table. I cleared first the 2 tables then executed the query.

Answer (score 0):

I cleared the 2 tables then executed the query.